# Can I pass multiple parameters to a custom validation function in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2.8.0. I have a custom validator function and I want to pass it 3 parameters. The first is obviously the $check, but the 2nd and 3rd are just some text to validate against. The second parameter comes through fine, but the third parameter always ends up being some array, when it should just be a string. Here's my validation rule and the function:

```
public $validate = array('commit_positions_funding_explain' => array(
                'check_empty_dependent' => array(
                        'rule' => array('check_empty_dependent', 'commit_positions_auth', '0'),
                        'message' => 'Please select an option',
                )
        ),);

public function check_empty_dependent($check, $parent, $another){
    //$another should be 0 but instead its an array that looks like the 
    //the validate array
    //do some stuff
    return true;
}
```

Any ideas on why that 3rd parameter is not working are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this array value was happening when I didn't pass that third parameter. The parameters for these validation functions cannot be optional. When I made sure that all validation rules calling this function were passing some value for $another, then everything worked fine.